# Get a custom array of the top level products categories in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

Is there any way to get list of top level products categories in woocomerce to display them in custom section within my theme

Here is the code I use, but it returns all categories:

```
function getCategoriesList() {

    // prior to wordpress 4.5.0
    $args = array(
        'number'     => $number,
        'orderby'    => $orderby,
        'order'      => $order,
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
        'include'    => $ids
    );

    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

    // since wordpress 4.5.0
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => "product_cat",
        'child_of'   => 0,
        'number'     => $number,
        'orderby'    => $orderby,
        'order'      => $order,
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
        'include'    => $ids
    );
    $product_categories = get_terms($args);

    $list = array();
    foreach( $product_categories as $cat ){ 
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        $link = get_term_link( $cat->term_id, 'product_cat' );
        $list[] = array($cat->term_id, $cat->name, $image, $link);        
    }

    return $list;

}
```

I have added recently:

```
'child_of'   => 0
```

But there is no change.

How to make it work for only top level product categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To get it works, the missing argument is just **`'parent' => 0`** *(but not `'child_of'`)*

So your working code should be something like this (and will return your array correctly:

```
function getProductCategoriesList() {

    // since wordpress 4.5.0
    $product_categories = get_terms( $args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => "product_cat",
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent'     => 0,
    ) );

    $list = array();

    foreach( $product_categories as $cat ){ 
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        $link = get_term_link( $cat->term_id, 'product_cat' );
        $list[] = array($cat->term_id, $cat->name, $image, $link);        
    }

    return $list;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works